# Cannot run a python package in amazon sagemaker, but can run it in amazon terminal?

Tags: terminal, package, amazon-sagemaker, fasttext

I am trying to use https://github.com/amzn/pecos in amazon sagemaker. I follow the readme of pecos to install it using amazon terminal. Then one can see the package is installed from terminal:

[image]

However, the package can not be used in a sagemaker:

[image]

So, why this happened and how to fix it?

P.S. I use the same way to install https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText and it can run in a sagemaker jupyter notebook.

Comment: Try running the following command in amazon sagemaker `!python3 -m pip install libpecos`

Comment: thanks for you comment. I have tried this before. Same errors: No module named 'pecos' or 'libpecos'